# Is there a reason to prefer one of these implementations over the other

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

In his PluralSight course **Asynchronous C# 5**, Jon Skeet provides this implementation for a convenience extension method called InCOmpletionOrder:

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> InCompletionOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> source)
{
    var inputs = source.ToList();
    var boxes  = inputs.Select(x => new TaskCompletionSource<T>()).ToList();
    int currentIndex = -1;

    foreach (var task in inputs)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(completed =>
        {
            var nextBox = boxes[Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex)];
            PropagateResult(completed, nextBox);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    return boxes.Select(box => box.Task);
}

private static void PropagateResult<T>(Task<T> completedTask,
      TaskCompletionSource<T> completionSource)
{
    switch(completedTask.Status)
    {
      case TaskStatus.Canceled:
          completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
          break;
      case TaskStatus.Faulted:
          completionSource.TrySetException(completedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions);
          break;
      case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
          completionSource.TrySetResult(completedTask.Result);
          break;
      default:
          throw new ArgumentException ("Task was not completed.");
    }
}
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720225/speculative-execution-using-the-tpl), Martin Neal provides a, seemingly more elegant, implementation using *yield return*

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> InCompletionOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> source)
{
    var tasks = source.ToList();

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var t = Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        yield return t.Result;
        tasks.Remove(t.Result);
    }
}
```

Being still somewhat new to the rigours of asynchronous programming, can anyone describe the specific concerns that might arise with Martin Neal's implementation that are properly resolved by Jon Skeet's more involved implementation

Comment: @MickyD: Exactly; but I hesitate to nearly quadruple the code volume until I understand, at least in broad strokes, why. **usr** has, below, provided me with two excellent reasons to do so.

Comment: Agreed. I just had a problem with "seemingly more elegant". One can not always equate line count with elegance for all aspects of programming. Servy makes some good points below. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second solution has a quadratic time complexity issue. The loop runs N times and each `WhenAny` call adds N continuations to those tasks. Don't use that code except if you know for sure that the number of tasks is very small.

The `Remove` call causes quadratic time complexity as well.

Also, the second piece of code is blocking. You only get back tasks as they complete. `InCompletionOrder` gives you those tasks immediately and they complete later.

I would regard `InCompletionOrder` as a library method. Put it into a utility file and it will not cause you maintenance problems. It's behavior will/can never change. I don't see code size as an issue here.

Comment: Jon's also handles excepted and cancelled tasks properly, whereas the other snippet basically only functions if all tasks complete successfully.  Honsetly that, and the fact that it's blocking (basically making the return type of `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` essentially a lie) are *far* more important than the performance issues, so I'd lead with those two points and only mention performance as a minor point.

Comment: @Servy are you sure about the exception behavior? The second snippet does not access the result of the tasks that it returns. The other point is well noted.